# How to put contents of file in a \path

Tags: pdftex, htlatex, url

Take the following file called "version"

```
5.1
```

I'd like to take the contents of version and insert in a \path. I've tried

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\begin{document}

\path{\input{version}}

\expandafter\path\expandafter{\input{version}}

\end{document}
```

which produces the following output.

[image: Output from program]

More specifically, I'd like something similar to

```
\path{C:\Program Files\My App\\input{version}}
```

To return

```
C:\Program Files\My App\5.1
```

Comment: Welcome! Did you try `catchfile`? (I may be misinterpreting the question since you do not really specify the contents of `version`.)

Comment: In this case, version is a major.minor version of some product, so 5.1 for example. The version number would be part of a bigger path, C:\Program Files\My Product\5.1 say

Comment: Sorry, I think there is miscommunication. Can you just add the example of the contents of `version.tex` to the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll be happy to remove this, but there is a chance you are looking for `catchfile`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{catchfile}
\begin{filecontents*}{version.txt}
5
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}

\CatchFileDef{\myversion}{version.txt}{}%
\expandafter\path\expandafter{\myversion}
\end{document}
```